# Migrating Jboss 5.1 Seam JBPM application to WildFly8.2

Tags: jbpm, wildfly-8

Currently I am working on migrating my seam jbpm application from Jboss 5.1 to WildFly 8.2

I am using Seam 2.2 and JBPM 3.3, deployed the jboss 5.1 application on WildFly 8.2 after compiling on java 8 and fixed few issues, I was blocked with a JBPM issue.

The below is my server log

```
4:12:50,540 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization] (MSC service thread         1-2) reading /WEB-INF/components.xml
    14:12:50,549 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./todo: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./todo: Failed to start service
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while reading /WEB-INF/components.xml
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:222)
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
  ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while reading /WEB-INF/components.xml
  at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.initComponentsFromXmlDocument(Initialization.java:231)
  at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.create(Initialization.java:134)
  at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:35)
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193)
  ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading element Jbpm with component name null and component class null
  at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.installComponentsFromXmlElements(Initialization.java:352)
  at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.initComponentsFromXmlDocument(Initialization.java:227)
  ... 11 more


14:12:50,567 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "todo-ear.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./todo" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./todo: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while reading /WEB-INF/components.xml
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while reading /WEB-INF/components.xml
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading element Jbpm with component name null and component class null"}}
14:12:50,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar")
14:12:50,709 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS018559: Deployed "todo-ear.ear" (runtime-name : "todo-ear.ear")
14:12:50,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./todo: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./todo: Failed to start service


14:12:50,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190/management
14:12:50,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
14:12:50,973 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 12043ms - Started 582 of 661 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 123 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
14:12:51,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'todo-ear.ear/todo-ejb.jar#todo'
14:12:51,145 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for D:\Migration_Workspace\Jboss\Jboss-8\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\standalone\deployments\todo-ear.ear\todo.war/]-0) Exception in thread "xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for D:\Migration_Workspace\Jboss\Jboss-8\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\standalone\deployments\todo-ear.ear\todo.war/]-0" java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException

The below is my comoponents.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components"
  xmlns:core="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/core" xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/persistence"
  xmlns:bpm="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/bpm" xmlns:security="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/security"
  xmlns:theme="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/theme" xmlns:cache="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/cache"
  xmlns:web="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/web" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/core http://jboss.org/schema/seam/core-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/persistence http://jboss.org/schema/seam/persistence-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/bpm http://jboss.org/schema/seam/bpm-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/security http://jboss.org/schema/seam/security-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/theme http://jboss.org/schema/seam/theme-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/cache http://jboss.org/schema/seam/cache-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/web http://jboss.org/schema/seam/web-2.3.xsd
                       http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components-2.3.xsd">


    <bpm:jbpm>
        <bpm:process-definitions>
        <value>todo.jpdl.xml</value>
        </bpm:process-definitions>
    </bpm:jbpm>

</components>
```

Please suggest me if anyone have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WildFly does not support JBPM 3.2, to solve this issue we need to use bundled hibernate jars as per the below link.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/253440